# Can I shorten this istream function?

Tags: c++, istream

```
friend istream& operator>>(istream &is, Complex &c) {
    int re;
    int im;

    is >> re >> im;
    c.setReal(re);
    c.setImaginary(im);

    return is;
}
```

Is there any way I could do this is one or two lines? Maybe something like,

```
is >> setReal() >> setImaginary();
```

Those functions take an int though, and I don't know how I would code that.

Comment: You could but why? It works and is very clear. I would argue that a shorter solution would be harder to read. To make it shorter, you would need to return a non-const reference to the fields of the Complex type then you could do `is >> c.real >> c.imaginary`

Comment: Please check the assembly language produced to see if there is good enough cause to reduce something to one line.  Personally, I like the clarity of the code in your post.

Comment: Your code doesn't fail correctly...

Comment: >>Those functions take an int though<< really? That would limit the complex plane to a fakir's bed... Or do they _return_ an int? I like your code as it is! Are you worried about speed?

Comment: The set functions each take an int for a parameter. I guess I'll keep it how I had it though.  I'm not worried about speed, I just didn't know if there was a simpler way to do it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Given your function is a `friend`, it has access to all the class's data members.  I assume you have a data member for each of the real and imaginary components, so you can change your code to avoid the set functions:

```
friend istream& operator>>(istream &is, Complex &c)
{
    return is >> c.re_ >> c.im_;  // or whatever you've called the data members...
}
```

As a general guideline, it's better to go through the public interface even if verbose, as it means you don't have to update this function's implementation just because you change some private implementation details (e.g. renaming those member variables, or changing your class to be a wrapper around a library's complex class), but if you value concision here more then that's your choice.

BTW /- Kerrek's comment is correct: your code doesn't fail correctly.  You might want to think about what state you want to leave both the Complex object and the stream in should either the real or the imaginary conversion fail....